# Can nomination be part of the workflow for CiviCase?

Tags: contacts, civicase

Historically, I've used CiviCRM for events and member management. I've never used CiviCase, but I think this situation probably calls for CiviCase. Any insight will be helpful.

In short, the client has asked for a form which allows a contact to nominate another individual to received funds from the organization relief fund. I want to record both the contact submitting the form and the eventual recipient and then the actions that client performs within their own workflow. I don't have that yet, because I was just handed a paper form to add to the system.

Am I in the right ballpark, to use CiviCase instead of just posting a profile form to go to the association? Will CiviCase allow me to track the submitter and the recipient more easily? Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: what cms are you using?

Comment: I'm working in a WP shop these days. My own shop, that I closed last year was a mix of Joomla and WP depending on the client needs. It's a small adjustment but it's working well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need CiviCase but it sounds like it could fit. You might also want to take a look at CiviGrant. For the form you might want to also look at https://civicrm.org/extensions/webform-civicrm-integration, especially if you're using cases since then it can generate a case from the form.

If not using cases, regular activities have both a submitter and "with contact" field to track submitter and recipient, or if you want to keep those fields for other purposes they can have custom contact reference fields.

The answer might also depend on what kind of reporting you need. For example cases might make it easier to count groups of related activities as one, e.g. if the same person gets nominated for funds again the next year.

Comment: What snagged me, was that I ultimately wanted to capture data about both the nominator and the nominee and I didn't see a simple way to manage two separate contacts in a simple profile. I appreciate the insight. I'll look at both options when I move on to the next phase. I have to roll out the new site this week for stage 1.